# Proper way to use "opposite boolean" in Pandas data frame boolean indexing

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, boolean

I wanted to use a boolean indexing, checking for rows of my data frame where a particular column does **not** have `NaN` values.  So, I did the following:

```
import pandas as pd
my_df.loc[pd.isnull(my_df['col_of_interest']) == False].head()
```

to see a snippet of that data frame, including only the values that are not `NaN` (most values are `NaN`).

It worked, but seems less-than-elegant.  I'd want to type:

```
my_df.loc[!pd.isnull(my_df['col_of_interest'])].head()
```

However, that generated an error.  I also spend a lot of time in R, so maybe I'm confusing things.  In Python, I usually put in the syntax "not" where I can.  For instance, `if x is not none:`, but I couldn't really do it here.  Is there a more elegant way?  I don't like having to put in a senseless comparison.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In general with pandas (and numpy), we use the bitwise NOT `~` instead of `!` or `not` (whose behaviour can't be overridden by types).

While in this case we have `notnull`, `~` can come in handy in situations where there's no special opposite method.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, np.nan, 3]})
>>> df.a.isnull()
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
>>> ~df.a.isnull()
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: a, dtype: bool
>>> df.a.notnull()
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

(For completeness I'll note that `-`, the unary negative operator, will also work on a boolean Series but `~` is the canonical choice, and `-` has been deprecated for numpy boolean arrays.)

Comment: it is a bit confusing as `~True` returns `-2`.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using [`pandas.isnull()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html#pandas.isnull) , you should use [`pandas.notnull()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notnull.html) to find the rows where the column has not null values. Example -

```
import pandas as pd
my_df.loc[pd.notnull(my_df['col_of_interest'])].head()
```

`pandas.notnull()` is the boolean inverse of [`pandas.isnull()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html#pandas.isnull) , as given in the documentation -

> See also
>   `pandas.notnull`
>   boolean inverse of pandas.isnull